# Is there a Python module for 2.5 that provides something similar to the "string".format() call in 2.6?

Tags: python, string

Is there a free Python module for 2.5 that provides something similar to the "string".format() call in 2.6/3.x?

I am writing new code for 2.5.  I'd rather not use % format expressions for new code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might find that the code here can be adapted to your need: http://svn.python.org/view/sandbox/trunk/pep3101/

In particular, you might be able to get StringFormat.py to run. It optionally imports a couple of things you might not have (like fpformat), but seems to be more or less robust if running as pure Python.

The PEP also references Genshi and Cheetah, which are templating engines that served as inspirations. One of those might work for you too.