# format command not working in older version of python

Tags: python

I wrote a python code which worked find on my laptop (python version 2.7.3), but it doesn't seem to run on my university desktop (python version 2.5.2).

I don't know if it is a version problem, but I got the error message about the following line:

```
os.chdir('../../pulsararchive/{0}'.format(pname))
```

and I got the following error message:

> AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'format'

Does the "format" thing not work in the older versions of python?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 `str.format`: New in version 2.6.
```

http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.format

See also [Is there a Python module for 2.5 that provides something similar to the "string".format() call in 2.6?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4643981/989121)

Answer (score 2):

No, the [`.format()` method](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) was not introduced until python 2.6.

You should use the old-style [`%` string formatting](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting) instead:

```
os.chdir('../../pulsararchive/%s' % pname)
```